# Jekyll _data: How to display the key-value label as a value, not just the value of the key

Tags: for-loop, jekyll, liquid

My data file example goes something like this:

_data/equipment.yaml

```
- ip_address: 192.168.0.1
   model: Netgear Whatever
   department: network
   location: Tempe, Arizona
   devicetype: Router
 - ip_address: 192.168.0.2
   model: T2000
   department: time travel
   location: 2035
   devicetype: weaponry
```

Now, I've managed to create a loop through the records, grouping them by department, displaying them each in their own table in a file called `_includes/equipment_list.html` which is called by `_pages/equipment_list_network.md`.

Where I'm stuck is how to make the first `<tr><td>` display the key labels as the column headers in the first `<tr>` of each table.

So, the table would look like:

```
| IP Address | Model | Department | Location | Etc. |
```

...without having to manually type out each TR/TD in separate files.  I'm aiming to have a *single* page that loads data based upon the page name, which would correspond with a filter in the `{% assign %}`:

```
{% assign departmentname = page.name | remove:"equipment_list_" | remove:".md" %} = results in "network" in this example.
```

Then...

```
{% assign equipment = site.data.equipment | where:"department",{{departmentname}} | group_by:"devicetype" %}
```

Then I just run a `for` loop to create a group header and then a `for` loop for each item in that group.

But, inserting the column names from the key labels in the data file is beyond my scope of understanding.

Any insight would be excellent.  I'm extremely new to programming and Jekyll...

Comment: I tried to clean your post up a bit, but I'm still not quite sure what you're asking. Can you please include a bit more code, preferably in the form of a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show actual example code, but I guess you're doing something like this, right?

```
<table>
{% for e in site.data.equipment %}
<tr>
    <td>{{e.ip_address}}</td>
    <td>{{e.model}}</td>
    <!-- etc. -->
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Note that **everything** in your data file is an object and has properties.

Instead of explicitly specifying `e.ip_address`, `e.model` etc., you can loop over `e`'s properties as well:

```
{% for item in e %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Each `item` is one of those key-value pairs - **and those have properties as well:

`item[0]` is the key and `item[1]` is the value.**

So we can loop over the data file and create a table with the values only:

```
<table>
{% for e in site.data.equipment %}
    <tr>
    {% for item in e %}
        <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

...and only in the [first loop](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops#forloop-first), show a header row with keys:

```
<table>
{% for e in site.data.equipment %}
    {% if forloop.first == true %}
    <tr>
    {% for item in e %}
        <th>{{item[0]}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
    {% for item in e %}
        <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

The last code example will generate the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ip_address</th>
        <th>model</th>
        <th>department</th>
        <th>location</th>
        <th>devicetype</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>192.168.0.1</td>
        <td>Netgear Whatever</td>
        <td>network</td>
        <td>Tempe, Arizona</td>
        <td>Router</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>192.168.0.2</td>
        <td>T2000</td>
        <td>time travel</td>
        <td>2035</td>
        <td>weaponry</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorta getting the hang of it.  Although, I'm not sure what the significance of the use of the letter 'e' is in the for loop.  I'm very new at this.  Is this just an arbitrary choice or is there a reason it's 'e'.

Comment: The example code was this:

`{% assign devices = site.data.network | group_by:"devicetype" }
<table>{% for devicteype in devices %}
  <tr><td>{{ devicetype.name }}</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td>IP</td>
  <td>MAC Address</td>
  <td>Etc...</td>
</tr>
{% for item in devicetype.items %}
<tr><td>{{item.ip}}</td></tr>
<tr> and so on...</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>`

Comment: It‘s an arbitrary choice. I loop site.data.equipment, and in each loop I need to assign the current piece of equipment to a variable, so I can access its properties (also see the first example in [the official docs about data files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/)). I chose e because I‘m too lazy to type a longer name :-) You used „devicetypes“ in your example.

Comment: I can't figure out how to put code into the comment box so it looks right.

Comment: Okay, so this works brilliantly, except that I have a more complicated arrangement.  Prior to the first `for` loop, I have:

`{% assign devices = site.data.equipment | where:"department", departmentname | group_by:"servicelocation" %}`

So, your example delivers 3 columns when I substitute `e` with `devices`.  1.  Name.  2.  Items.  3.  Size.

How would I accomplish the same result as your example when the data has been grouped, and the group key `items` contains the key=>value pairs that I need to be column labels.  Thanks!